# How to get data from one table column in other table column in ServiceNow?

Tags: servicenow

I have made a ServiceNow application whose workflow is:

1. User creates a new incident using the 'Create New' module in Incident.
2. After the incident is submitted, a KA number (Knowledge Article) is assigned to it based on its short description and other fields. The assignment of KA number is     done by my Python script.
3. The incident and its KA number is stored in a table named 'Knowledge Applied to Tasks (m2m_kb_task)'. Incident is stored in m2m_kb_task in 'task' column. It is         stored as a link which points to 'Task' table. (Some background information: incident table extends task table. 'Number' column in task is used as the incident         number). In the same way, the KA number is stored in m2m_kb_task under 'kb_knowledge' column. It is also stored as a link which points to 'kb_knowledge' table.
4. When the user clicks on an incident present in the list, she can see the knowledge article attached to that incident in Related Links -> Attached Knowledge tab

However, I want the Knowledge article number (Example - KB0000011) to be stored in the incident table too. It should be stored against the incident to which it is mapped.

Is there a way to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps to open article page when you click on `Attached Knowledge tab` ui action on related links.

Step 1: Create new UI action on `incident` form

Step 2: Open the ui action form and see that `form link` checkbox is checked (true). And `Client` checkbox is unchecked (false)

Step 3: Paste the below code in Script section.

```js
var m2mGr = new GlideRecord('m2m_kb_task');
m2mGr.addQuery('task', current.sys_id); // current represents incident on opened page
m2mGr.query();

if(m2mGr.next()){
    action.setRedirectURL("/kb_view.do?sys_kb_id="+m2mGr.kb_knowledge); // Open article view

  //In case you what to open knowledge record instead of view.
   /*
    var kbGr = new GlideRecord('kb_knowledge');
    kbGr.get(m2mGr.kb_knowledge)
    action.setRedirectURL(kbGr);
   */
} else {
    gs.addInfoMessage("No article found related to incident :" + current.sys_id)
}
```

If you think there will be multiple articles attached to incident, then better show the list page of knowledge to task. You can do that by using below code simply.

```js
action.setRedirectURL("/m2m_kb_task_list.do?sysparm_query=task.sys_id%3D" + current.sys_id + "&sysparm_first_row=1&sysparm_view=");
```

PFA screenshot of UI Action form.

[image]

Comment: My intention is to get the KA number and send that along with short description to an external system using REST message and business rules. That is the reason I want to store KA number in incident table, as short description is also stored in incident table

Comment: why don't you simply query it just before making the REST call.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I am a newbie with Service Now development hence can you give a code snippet or steps to achieve the above mentioned requirement? Do I need to query the m2m_kb_task table in my business rule considering the fact that my business rule is based on incident table.

Comment: @PratikHaware: I can help you with that. Can you elaborate your use case? 

When the user clicks on `Attached Knowledge tab` you wish to show him a list of knowledge articles attached to it? (as in new page list view or another view like a modal window)

Comment: @PratikHaware: updated the above answer with a code snippet :)

Comment: Thanks Shivaji :)